# Boot error when trying to use Dotenv with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to use `DotEnv` gem in my Ruby app and I keep getting a

```
Boot Error uninitialized constant Dotenv
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development do
   gem 'dotenv', :groups => [:development]
end
```

And my `.app` looks like this:

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

Finally my `.env` file looks like this:

```
consumer_key=xxxx
consumer_secret=xxx
oauth_token=xxx
oauth_token_secret=xxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Bundler are you using? I'm looking at [the docs for v1.6 and they use a slightly different syntax](http://bundler.io/v1.6/groups.html) (`group`, not `groups`, and not inside a block).

Comment: I am using bundler version 1.5.1

Answer (score -3):

To solve the problem I restarted the server.